# Need help setting up Karma (Getting an error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am new to Karma and would really appreciate any help understanding the reason for the error below:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.controllers' is not available!
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives'
]).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

**StoreCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').
  controller('StoreCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
```

**StoreCtrl.spec.js**

```
describe('StoreCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the
        // parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.filterByPrice', function() {
        it('test spec', function() {

        });
    });
});
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
    'public/js/scripts/angular/angular.js',
    'public/js/scripts/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'public/js/scripts/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
    'public/js/app.js',
    'public/js/controllers/*.js',
    'tests/**/*.spec.js'
],
```

**File Structure**

[image]

Comment: app.js needs the other files, so you need to load that one last

Comment: @devqon,Thank you for your response but that did not solve my problem. Fortunately, I figured out the issue and posted the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Karma wasn't picking the controllers.js file before the StoreCtrl.js

I had to change the code below:

```
'public/js/controllers/*.js',
```

to

```
'public/js/controllers/controllers.js',
'public/js/controllers/StoreCtrl.js',
```

and it works now :)